# Changing display names for monitor checks in ActiveXperts Network Monitoring Software

Tags: powershell, vbscript, powershell-3.0

I have a folder in ActiveXperts with display names in the format ConstantName1-VaringName(example:abc-xyz,abc-lmn,abc-ijk)Is there a way to change the ConstantName1-VaringName for all monitor check display names  to Constant2-VaringName.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), SO is more orientated towards coding.

Comment: Some context on what exactly "ActiveXperts" is would be helpful, as would some examples of code you have attempted to created to solve this problem and what issues/confusion you have run into.  to get you started (and assuming that ActiveXperts folders are generic windows directories) you should look into [Rename-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176940.aspx)

Comment: [ActiveXperts Network Monitoring Software](http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/) the folders are inside the program itself and used for organising the checks the program performs. This isn't really a question for SO and is better suited for Server Fault.